# Throwing Custom exception in XMLAdapter

Tags: jaxb

I am using XMLAdapter to marshal and unmarshal Dates. In my unmarshaller I want to check the format being supplied from the REST service. If the format is wrong then I want to throw an exception of my own. However, the expetion is being eaten up and the application moves on. I know the solution lies with *ValidationEventHandler* but I am not able to figure out how to use it exactly. PLease help with ways to use it. My XMLAdapter code is like this

```
public class DateFormatAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

@Override
public String marshal(Date arg0) throws Exception {

    return arg0.toString();
}

@Override
public Date unmarshal(String arg0) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);
    Date startDate = null;
    try {
        startDate = df.parse(arg0);
        df.format(startDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // throw custom exception from here
    }

    return startDate;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Thats true! If you throw an Exception inside an implementation of XMLAdapter, it will be catched and the service continues. The status of the response wont be set to `Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` or something else. Insted the data isn't mapped and thus the response doesn't contain the desired data. If you want to influence the response code, in case that the data format doesn't match, you have to throw the exception within the data entity itself. In your case you have to create a CustomDate class which extends Date and then call from the constructor a validation method. Furthermore an apdapter class isn't considered to do data validation, hence the approach with the custom date class and an optional validation proxy is much more convenient.

Comment: Ya it seems to be a feasible way. I will try this and update.